# Add extensions to notepadqq

Tags: notepadqq

I'm new to Notepadqq but a bit familiarised with Notepad++.

I wonder if can download worthy extensions for coding quickly.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are none. Searched for them for the past hour. Also, "About notepadqq" 2018 was the last year it was worked on.